# Trying to query MongoDB with Javascript, returns empty

Tags: javascript, mongodb

This always returns an empty array.

```
<!--
tid - int64
ts - timestamp
url - string
topic - string
msg - string
-->

<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stitch-sdks/js/bundles/4.3.1/stitch.js"></script>
<script>
    const client = stitch.Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient("twebh-rufmj");

    const db = client
        .getServiceClient(stitch.RemoteMongoClient.factory, "mongodb-atlas")
        .db("forums");

    client.auth
        .loginWithCredential(new stitch.AnonymousCredential())
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        })
        .then(displayEmployees);

    function displayEmployees() {
        db.collection("posts")
            .find({}, { limit: 1000 })
            .toArray()
            .then(docs => {
                const html = docs.map(doc => `<div>${doc.topic}</div>`);
                document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML = html;
            });
    }
</script>

<div id="comments"></div>
```

I expect the returned topic to be "test" as that's what I have for a record in the database. I tried lots of different example code from the MongoDB wiki, but this returns no errors in Chrome's console, yet I don't get a returned value.

Comment: Did you  try to debug by console logging your return values ?  It's the easiest way to find out what is going wrong.

Comment: also can you run those queries alone either using `curl` or mongo UI editors like `robo mongo` or `NoSQLBooster`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you are not getting any value from your `db query` is because there is slight issue with your `find` query.

You are passing `limit :1000` as the second argument of `find` query, but it should be the third argument. Second argument is supposed to be the `projection`, and third argument is the `query options`(where limit is passed)

You need to pass empty object as second argument and `{limit:1000}` as the third argument.

Also, it would be better if you do a `.join()` after `map`, so that it returns a string instead of an array to `innerHTML`

**Try this :**

```
function displayEmployees() {
    db.collection("posts")
        .find({}, {}, { limit: 1000 })
        .toArray()
        .then(docs => {
            const html = docs.map(doc => `<div>${doc.topic}</div>`).join('');
            document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML = html;
        });
}
```